# Replacing the index of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The question I need to solve for a given data frame is:
Replace the index of mydf with ['one','two','three','four','five'].

I have written this code:

```
mydf_indexed = mydf[index=['one','two','three','four','five']]
```

However, it gives the error "Invalid syntax". I could not understand what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is there like a specific index that they give you?

Comment: `my_df.index = ['one','two','three','four','five']`